# Data is fetching properly but why is it not displaying?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react hooks to fetch an api and show the list of NBA players first and last name. Fetching API is successful as it can be shown in log but it's not displaying the names. 
Free API I used:https://www.balldontlie.io/

//react component to fetch and show data

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const refreshData = useCallback(() => {
    fetch("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My player</h1>
      <ul>
        {Object.values(data).map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

The `data` is an object with two keys, `data` and `meta`, neither of which are objects of players with first and last name properties.

```
// 20211018232429
// https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 14,
      "first_name": "Ike",
      ...
      "last_name": "Anigbogu",
      ...
    },
    ...
    {
      "id": 497,
      "first_name": "Michael",
      ...
      "last_name": "Ansley",
      ...
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    ....
  }
}
```

## Solution

You want to map the `data` property which is the array of player objects.

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const refreshData = useCallback(() => {
    fetch("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.data); // <-- save data.data array
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
  }, [refreshData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My player</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => ( // <-- map data array
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

  const refreshData = React.useCallback(() => {
    fetch("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.data);
      });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    refreshData();
  }, [refreshData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My player</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            {item.first_name} {item.last_name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't update state with actual value. you passed object into state.
Here is what you have to just pass to access the values:

```
const refreshData = useCallback(() => {
fetch("https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/players")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
setData(data.data);
console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);
```